# Adding a variable passed from views.py into a static file in a template

Tags: python, html, django

I have 4 pdfs files with names such as "lesson-1, lesson-2, lesson-3" etc. I want each of them to render when the path for each one is accessed. How can I pass the variable from views.py into the static link from the template?

I've tried:

```html
{% static 'lectii/lectie-' | add:{lectie}.pdf %}
{% static 'lectii/lectie-{lectie}.pdf %}
```

and none worked.

Here's the template:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    </div>
    <div id="middle-section" class="container-fluid container-fluid-margin">
        <div class="row content-block">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <embed src="{% static 'lectii/lectie-{lectie}.pdf %}" style="width: 100%; height: 100vh;"></embed>    
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row content-block">
            <iframe width="100%" height="750" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/I6dQXpJKlPk" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from .models import Lectie

def lectii(req):
    return render(req, '../templates/pagini/lectii-selector.html')

def lectie(req, lectie_id):
    lectie2 = get_object_or_404(Lectie, pk=lectie_id)
    context = {
        'lectie': lectie2
    }
    return render(req, '../templates/pagini/lectii.html', context)
```

(lectie = lesson)

So how can I include the variable into that static path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the simplest way is:

```
src="{% static 'lectii/lectie' %}-{{ lectie }}.pdf"
```